# Drawing a sprite with XNA results in the white pixels in the background of the picture being Rendered too

Tags: c#, xna

Whenever I load a sprite (png file) with XNA framework, it results in a white rectangle behind the sprite. How do I filter this out? My code is below

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(MySprite, MySpritePosition, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

[image: The Image]

Comment: You should try using an image you are 100% sure has transparent background, because it seems that your image may have a white background.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to use `spriteBatch.Draw()` method with `Color.Transparent`? This usually makes your sprite invisible. Try using `Color.White` instead. Can you add a screenshot of your problem to the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably due to the fact the image itself has a white background. Try to resave it with a transparent background.

**EDIT**

The image you post shows the background is actually white instead of transparent. Changing this depends on the tool you are using for drawinf the image. Try wit google `<<your tool name>>` making transparent background.

Comment: You probably mean resaving it with white background set to transparent.

Comment: I added the image thats having the problem

Comment: Thanks, I used Paint.net to add the transparent background and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RGB 255, 0, 255 for the background instead of white if you cant make it transparent for some reason. XNA's draw method filters out 255, 0, 255 as a "magic" color.